# A doubt regarding the proof of "the set of nilpotent elements is an ideal".

Tags: commutative-algebra

On pg.5 of "Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah-Macdonald, Proposition 1.7 states that

> The set $A$ of all nilpotent elements in a commutative ring $R$ is an ideal.

Let $x,y\in A$. Clearly, for any $n\in \Bbb{N}$, $x^n\neq 0$ and $y^n\neq 0$. However, why can't $(xy)^n=x^ny^n=0$? Nowhere is it stated that $R$ is an integral domain. And if $xy\notin A$, then $A$ is not an ideal.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in A$ then it means that $x^n=0$ for some $n$. You are trying to prove that the set of elements which are NOT nilpotent are an ideal, which of course is not true.

**P.S.** Here are two hints for the proof:

If $x,y \in A$ then $x^n=0$ and $y^m=0$ for some $m,n$. Then $(x+y)^{m+n}=0$.

Also, if $x \in A, r \in R$ then $x^n=0$ hence $(rx)^n=0$.

Comment: Oh! I switched the definitions! Sorry.